# How to exports models with node-orm?

Tags: node.js, orm, models

I'm testing [node-orm](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm) and I can't find the correct way to export models. Here is the model definition (./models/user.js):

```
var orm = require('orm');

var db = orm.connect('pg://user@localhost/accounts', function(success, db) {
  if (!success) {
    console.log('Could not connect to database.');
    return;
  }

  var User = db.define('user', {
    ... // Model schema
  });

  module.exports = User;
});
```

And when I try to use it elsewhere (e.g. ./app.js):

```
var User = require('./models/user');
...

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var user = new User({
    ...
  });
  user.save(function(err, user) {
    ...
  });

  ...
});
```

Turns out that User is an empty object so node can't call the model constructor. What is the proper way to export a model with node-orm ? That's probably simple but I find anything in the docs…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're setting your `module.exports` in a callback function. Node's [module loading system](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) specifically states that you cannot do that.

The `orm-node` module stores your models in its module exports with the name that you specify for your model. Your example should work if you change your `app.js` to read:

```
require('./models/user');
var orm = require('orm');
...

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
  var user = new orm.user({
    ...
  });
  user.save(function(err, user) {
    ...
  });

  ...
});
```

Also note that because your model is initialized in a callback it is not immediately available after you `require()` your model module. Presumably you'll have completed your database connection and model initialization before you need to process a get of `/user`.

Probably the safest way to handle all this would be to make sure your application initialization and `listen()` are done as a part of that `orm.connect()` callback.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that works better now. The problem with the callback is that I want to seperate my models in different files. I can probably put my models definition in different files and import them in the callback…

Answer (score 0):

It is how I do it with [light-orm](https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm):

```
var ORM = require('light-orm');

var AdsCollection = new ORM.Collection({
    connector: ORM.driver,
    tableName: 'ads'
});

module.exports = AdsCollection;
```

Should be pretty similar with your ORM. I have migrated from [node-orm](https://npmjs.org/package/orm) to [light-orm](https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm) because of magic issues and complexity. You may look at light-orm also:
https://npmjs.org/package/light-orm